I answered a more general version of my own question. How should I proceed?
A week or two ago I asked this question, When does $n! = a\cdot 2^a$. In which, I proposed a question, added where the question came from and where the question could go, and then answered it and asked for feedback or better proofs. I received a proof which was much neater than the one I had proposed; however, it didn't answer the more general version of the question: when does $n! = a \cdot b^a$. I realize that if I wanted an answer for this I would have to ask another question as the original question was not focused on that. However, I now believe I have found a proof for the more general question and am not sure of whether or not I should post it on the original question.
I have seen some negative feedback when people immediately answer their own questions so I am skeptical of posting the more general solution and answering it myself. However, I also feel like the more general proof might be off topic on my original question. Should I post another "solution-verification" question or would that not be well received as I am fairly confident that the proof is sound and neat as possible?

Your general solution doesn't look off topic to me in that question.

I would suggest you ask a new question.  Our goal is to build a knowledge base that will be useful to others in the future.
I've seen two kinds of pushback against self-answered questions: (1) reasonable concerns, and (2) bias against self-answered question.  Regarding (1), make sure that your question stands on its own and would be considered high-quality even if you hadn't posted an answer.  I've seen situations where people don't spend as much time crafting a good question when they already have an answer.  Regarding (2), it's true.  Our site philosophy is supposed to encourage self-answered questions.  But everyone is free to vote as they choose.  And I too have sometimes seen similar behavior, where self-answered questions are held to higher scrutiny.
I encourage you to do the "right thing" (i.e., what benefits the mission of the site), and ask a new question about this more general case.  But I would also completely understand if you are reluctant to do so for fear of receiving downvotes.

Separately, I notice that your existing question ask multiple questions: (a) can someone verify my proof about when $n!=a2^a$?, (b) is there a more elegant proof?, (c) is there a proof of when $n!=ab^a$?  That's problematic.  On this site, we ask you to ask one question per post.
Also, proof verification questions (asking us to verify your proof) are considered inappropriate here.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info.
I think a better thing to do would have been to ask for a proof of when $n!=a2^a$.  Then, you could ask a separate question, requesting a proof of when $n!=ab^a$.

Re: fear of downvotes: be brave and noble - the goal of disseminating mathematical knowledge should infinitely trump puerile gamification. $\ \ $
